# Мобильный редирект работает не правильно

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, редирект, mobile

Здравствуйте. Сделал редирект на внутреннюю страницу (skidkus.kz/mobilesearch) для мобильных пользователей через .htaccess Он работает. Проблема в том что на этой странице размещена форма поиска, результаты которой уходят в ошибку 404 (если заходить с мобил. браузера). Вот мой htaccess

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:midp|samsung|nokia|j2me|avant|docomo|novarra|palmos|palmsource|opwv|chtml|pda|mmp|blackberry|mib|symbian|wireless|nokia|hand|mobi|phone|cdm|upb|audio|SIE|SEC|samsung|HTC|mot-|mitsu|sagem|sony|alcatel|lg|eric|vx|NEC|philips|mmm|xx|panasonic|sharp|wap|sch|rover|pocket|benq|java|pt|pg|vox|amoi|bird|compal|kg|voda|sany|kdd|dbt|sendo|sgh|gradi|jb|dddi|moto|iphone|android) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} skidkus.kz
RewriteRule ^$ http://skidkus.kz/mobilesearch [R=302,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? Может лучше редирект через php?

Comment: Куда вы отправляете человека с мобильным телефоном после отправки формы на странице mobilesearch?

Comment: Там получается ссылка вида /?unonce=f4a0bc54a7&uformid=..... Я точно не знаю какой там механизм там работает плагин на Wordpress

Comment: Этот плагин создал страницу для отображения результата skidkus.kz/search

Comment: Ваш .htaccess все запросы с мобильных отправляет на одну страницу. В том числе запрос с формы уходит не по назначению. Условие редиректа мобильных нужно более точное. То есть, например, редиректить только зашедших в первый раз или с другого сайта и т.д.

Comment: не знаю как это реализовать. не силен в коде правда.

Comment: А почему вы говорите все запросы отправляет на 1одну страницу? К примеру skidkus.kz/about или /apply а также ссылки на посты /opus/1 и др. не перенаправляются. Только с главной.

Comment: попробуйте тогда после строки `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} skidkus.kz` поставить строку `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Незнаю как но заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мой ответ из комментариев.**
Причина появления 404 ошибки в том, что данные из формы уходят на index.php методом GET (вы об этом написали)

> /?unonce=f4a0bc54a7&ufor...

но на index.php для мобильных устройств устройств у вас срабатывает редирект

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:midp|samsung|nokia|j2me|avant|docomo|novarra|palmos|palmsource|opwv|chtml|pda|mmp|blackberry|mib|symbian|wireless|nokia|hand|mobi|phone|cdm|upb|audio|SIE|SEC|samsung|HTC|mot-|mitsu|sagem|sony|alcatel|lg|eric|vx|NEC|philips|mmm|xx|panasonic|sharp|wap|sch|rover|pocket|benq|java|pt|pg|vox|amoi|bird|compal|kg|voda|sany|kdd|dbt|sendo|sgh|gradi|jb|dddi|moto|iphone|android) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} skidkus.kz
RewriteRule ^$ http://skidkus.kz/mobilesearch [R=302,L]
```

в результате открывается страница

```
/mobilesearch?unonce=f4a0bc54a7&ufor...
```

Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно добавить в данный редирект еще одно условие с проверкой отсутствия параметров GET в адресной строке

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```